# MySQL : using datetime or timestamp for logged in history

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing an application where i have to store login and logout time for employees , now this  is the logic

1- i'll query  loggedin field to check if  any   value exists for today if not  save current time (so i've to query and manipulate this value )

2- For logout every logout is  last logout , so i've to keep track  of the date to make sure  last value is saved for today's date

3- there from admin panel i've to add functionality to search login / logout histroy using a  jquery  date picker ,

so as per this criteria  can you guys please suggest me which  one should i go for , i went through official docs but  could not get this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both fit for your requirement.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Some difference:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

Comment: And for  date picker also they are okay ?  as that's a  calendar and I've to search against these fields  ..

Comment: Look above at their format. DateTime: '9999-12-31 23:59:59', TimeStamp:  '2038-01-19 03:14:07' . Same-same. If one works for your UI date-picker, then the other would also.